# When to use labels and relation types indexing from Neo4j 4.3?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I've [already asked it on the Neo4j forum](https://community.neo4j.com/t/when-to-use-labels-and-relation-types-indexing-from-neo4j-4-3/40187), hoping for more success here.

In NODES 2021, label and type indices, available from the 4.3 server, were presented. However, I haven't clear when I should or should not use this kind of indices.

Naively, I tend to think that in most cases, there will be searches like `MATCH ( n: ) - [r:] -> (...)`. So, I'd say it's good to have them in most cases.

But maybe I'm wrong? Maybe they benefit more certain types of queries only?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I got an answer [on the Neo4j forum](https://community.neo4j.com/t/when-to-use-labels-and-relation-types-indexing-from-neo4j-4-3/40187).

Essentially, label/type indices are useful for filters on label/types like: WHERE label = x OR label = y.